# Add n months to a pandas Period object?

Tags: python, pandas, period

This seems like it should be easy but I can find no answer when googling. Say I have some variable k that is of type pandas.Period, and whose value is:

```
Period('2018-11', 'M')
```

How do I add n months to this variable. For example if n is 3 i would want k to be

```
Period('2019-02', 'M')
```

I have tried the following:

```
k.month = k.month + 12
```

But this fails saying:

```
AttributeError: attribute 'month' of 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period._Period' objects is not writable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a [`pd.offsets`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).`MonthEnd` object:

```
pd.Period('2018-11', 'M') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(3)
```

Comment: `from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset` then `p + 3*to_offset('M')`

Comment: I think your answer is wrong, output should be `2019-02`

Comment: Problem is `print (pd.Timedelta(3, unit='M'))
91 days 07:27:18`

Comment: @jezrael not home to test, but perhaps DateOffset can be used instead of Timedelta?

Comment: @coldspeed - yes, it should be way, but here overcomplicated.

Comment: @jezrael Okay, I guessed there might be a better way, and I was right, your way is definitely simpler. I've upvoted it!

Comment: @coldspeed - Thank you, I really do it too, but answer is wrong. :(

Comment: @jezrael Aha, it was an `offset` object after all. Thank you for the edit :)

Answer (score 5):

Because you add months to month period, only use `+`:

```
k = pd.Period('2018-11', 'M')
print (k)
2018-11

k1 = k + 3
print (k1)
2019-02

k2 = k + 12
print (k2)
2019-11
```